# Get mySQL rows from today using the hour

Tags: mysql, sql, date

Is it possible to `SELECT` all rows from just today using `DATE('today')` and then grab rows based on a specified hour?

I'm assuming it'd be something like so? (I know it's not the correct syntax)

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    `table`
WHERE
    DATE(`datetime`) = DATE(`today`) 
AND
    HOUR(`datetime`) = '23'
```

Bare in the mind the `datetime` column is in `datetime` format

Comment: Try `DATE(datetime) = CURRENT_DATE()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`NOW()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now) to get the current datetime, or [`CURDATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curdate) to get the date only, and then the [`DATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) and [`HOUR()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_hour) functions:

```
SELECT *
FROM my_table
WHERE DATE(my_datetime_field) = CURDATE() /* or DATE(NOW()) */
AND HOUR(my_datetime_field) = 23;
```